# Intestazione lettera: "Ciao Tizio" o "Ciao, Tizio"?

Tags: punctuation, interjections

Nell'intestazione di una lettera, quando ci si rivolge al destinatario, è corretto usare la forma seguente?

> Ciao, Tizio.
>   [corpo del testo]

Convinto di dover usare un vocativo come

> Ehi, Tizio!
>   Ciao, Caio!

Ho sempre usato questa forma, ma vedo molto frequentemente utilizzata quest'altra versione:

> Ciao Caio,
>   [corpo del testo]

Quale dei due formati è più corretto?

Comment: Buona domanda. Anch'io preferisco la forma “Ciao, Tizio.”, ma vedo diffusissima la seconda che, ipotizzo, mantiene la struttura formale di “Caro Caio, ...” ma fa a meno del “caro” sentito forse come troppo intimo (o troppo formale?). Comunque, ovviamente “Ciao, Tizio.” non può non essere corretta.

Comment: Io tendo a non aprire mai una lettera/mail con un ciao, preferisco tenerlo come saluto finale. *Caro Tizio*,  o semplicemente *Tizio*, penso siamo  due maniere valide per rivolgersi in maniera informale ad una persona amica o conosciuta.

Comment: Dopo un saluto, il nome assume il valore di un vocativo, che solitamente è separato dal resto del discorso da una virgola.

Comment: Anch'io tante volte ho avuto questo dubbio.

Comment: I miei libri di grammatica per studenti stranieri hanno questi esempi di possibili formule di saluto: «Ciao, Sabrina, come stai?» (Federica Colombo, *Grammatica e pratica della lingua italiana per studenti stranieri*, edizioni ELI). «Ciao Antonio! Come stai?» (Maria Cristina Peccianti, *Grammatica italiana per stranieri*, Giunti Editori). L'esempio del primo libro ha la virgola dopo «ciao», invece l'esempio del secondo ce l'ha dopo il nome (dopo «Sabrina»).

Answer (score 3):

Io preferisco la seconda. Prima di esplicarne le motivazioni sia da considerare che, essendo una lettera colloquiale, queste differenze hanno meno valore, perché semplicemente non si presta attenzione a ciò poiché non dovrebbe esserci interesse nel farlo, a differenza di una lettera formale.

> Ciao, Tizio.
>   [corpo del testo]

mostra subito il "problema": il messaggio da comunicare sembra già terminato dal punto fermo; tale forma la vedrei più appropriata alla chiusura del messaggio. D'altra parte,

> Ciao Caio,
>   [corpo del testo]

la virgola ha funzione sospensiva del messaggio effettivo, introducendolo, se vogliamo. Infatti, l'effetto desiderato è esattamente quello che ti ritroveresti a riprodurre se il messaggio fosse comunicato oralmente, con una intonazione naturale.

Certo, se il tuo intento è quello la prima versione sarebbe preferibile, almeno per me. Dipende da cosa vuoi esprimere e come.

Comment: Effettivamente, nel primo formato viene chiusa la frase mentre nel secondo viene presentato subito il corpo del messaggio. Non ci avevo pensato...

Comment: E cosa ne dici di questa soluzione? --> _Ciao, Tizio,_

Comment: @MauroVanetti Lo vedo più appropriato in mancanza dell'accapo, quindi: "Ciao, Tizio, come stai?"